# How to find minNumber of operations such that binary string of length N is all zeros?

Tags: python, algorithm

How to find minNumber of operations such that binary string of length N is all zeros?

choose two adjacent character and replace both of them with their xor value.

for example take binary string "101"

pick 1st and 2nd and xor => 111

pick 1st and 2nd and xor => 001

pick 2nd and 3rd and xor => 011

pick 2nd and 3rd and xor => 000

so the minimum number of operations is 4

here is my attempt

```
def checkAllZeros(astr):
    for each_char in astr:
        if each_char == 1:
            return False
    return True


def getMinOperations(astr):
    totalOps = 0
    while checkAllZeros(astr):
        i = 0
        j = 1
        if j < len(astr):
            if (astr[i] == '0' and astr[j] == '1') or (astr[i] == '1' and astr[j] == '0'):
                astr = astr[0:i] + '11' + astr[i + 2:]
                totalOps += 1
            elif astr[i] == '1' and astr[j] == '1':
                astr = astr[0:i] + '00' + astr[i + 2:]
                totalOps += 1
                i += 1
                j += 1
            else:
                i += 1
                j += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(getMinOperations('1111'))
```

I am assuming this requires dynamic programming? somehow it doesnt work on big strings

Comment: I don't really understand your example. Wouldn't the first step already lead to `011`?

Comment: the input is 101. so as a first step if I pick first two and then replace their positions with xor value then it is 111

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update:

we can break it down like this:

'00' -> 0 (times)

'01' -> 2

'10' -> 2

'11' -> 1

so the answer can be this:

```py
astr = '1101010010111'
operations = 0
operations += astr.count('11')
astr = astr.replace('11', '')
operations += sum(list(map(int, astr))) * 2
print(operations) # 10
```

---

How to define an 'operation'?

for example:

```py
astr = '110111'
sumOne = sum(list(map(int, astr)))
operations = sumOne // 2 + sumOne % 2
print(operations) # 3
```

pick 1st and 2nd and xor => 000111

pick 4th and 5th and xor => 000001

pick 5th and 6th and and => 000000

so the minimum number of operations is 3

the problem is that whether find the index of '1' using an 'operation'

Comment: anytime you pick two adjacent bits and replace their position with xor of their values it is an operation. the goal is to find minimum number of operation so you can turn any arbitrary binary string with a string of all zeros

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for all the cases. For example if I input `1101010010111` the minimum number of operations is 10 but the above code returns 4

Comment: input: `1101` expected output: 3 above code returns 2
input `110101` expected output: 5 above code returns 2

Comment: I think I just misunderstood your question description. Yeah, this answer is wrong.

Comment: we can break it down like this:

00 -> 0

01 -> 2

10 -> 2

11 -> 1

```
astr = '1101010010111'

operations = 0

operations += astr.count('11')

astr = astr.replace('11', '')

operations += sum(list(map(int, astr))) * 2

print(operations) # 10
```

Comment: what is the error? the output in my local is 499.

Comment: works! sorry I pasted your wrong code